# Mocking External HTTP Requests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, lettuce

I have a class which goes out to an external server and, naturally, retrieves data for which I do some processing.  I really need to unit test this whole thing, but I do not want to keep hitting the external server every time I make my request.  My question:  What is the proper protocol for this?  I'm using lettuce, but I'm also open to other ideas.

Here is my class:

```
## in my class
class SomeClass:
    def doHttpGet(self):
        ## return request from http://somewhere.com
```

What should happen is I override doHttpGet...

```
class SomeClass:
    def doHttpGet(self):
        ## return { "some": "data", "which": "mocks" }
```

Comment: Have you seen: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/ ?

Comment: For what it's worth, in my http get code, I have a global `if TESTING: ...` statement that re-routes all remote http requests to static test files residing on my system. Not the most elegant, but it works.

Comment: How do you get the data from `somewhere.com`? Is it via `urllib(2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) for testing networking.

Wrap your network API with a class, e.g. NetworkManager. Its method makeRequest() will make the real HTTP request.

```
class NetworkManager:
    def makeRequest(self):
        # Do an HTTP request to the server, return response
```

Unit tests must use a mock class of NetworkManager, which overrides makeRequest() method and returns needed testing data without touching the network:

```
class MockNetworkManager(NetworkManager):
    def makeRequest(self):
        return testingResponse
```

Your SomeClass class must make HTTP requests via the network manager class. In production environment, it will use an instance of NetworkManager and do real network requests. In testing environment, SomeClass will use an instance of MockNetworkManager.

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, network):
        network = network

    def doHttpGet(self):
        response = self.network.makeRequest()
```

In production code:

```
some = SomeClass(NetworkManager())
some.doHttpGet()
```

In unit tests:

```
some = SomeClass(MockNetworkManager())
some.doHttpGet()
```